# Oracle Error "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle error '80040e14' ORA-00936: missing expression /secure/databoks/behandl_databoks.asp, line 49"

Tags: oracle

```
%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% option explicit %>
<!-- #include virtual="/secure/inc/logged_on.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/secure/inc/resettimer.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/secure/databoks/inc/open_dbox_db.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/secure/inc/functions.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/secure/databoks/inc/dbox_functions.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="adovbs.inc" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/secure/inc/security_functions.asp" -->  <% ' #2758 %>
<%
Dim setkomma
Dim aktfilid
Dim sSQL
Dim item

If Request.Form("slettet") <> "" Then
    sSQL = "UPDATE dbox_files SET slettet = sysdate WHERE kundenr = " &     Session("kundenummer") & " and brugernr = '" & Session("rkibrugernummer") & "' and slettet       is null and filid in("

setkomma = false


    For Each item In Request.Form("slettet")    
        aktfilid = trim(item)
      session("_logger").debug "asp.databoks/behandl_databoks", "(1) aktfilid: " &     aktfilid
            If setkomma Then
                sSQL = sSQL & ","
            End if
            sSQL = sSQL & aktfilid
            setkomma = true
    Next
    sSQL = sSQL & ")"


    Dim objCmd
    Dim Rec
    const adCmdText = &H0001
    Const adVarChar = 200
    Const adParamInput =  &H0001
    set objCmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        objCmd.ActiveConnection = DBoxConn
        objCmd.CommandType =adCmdText
        objCmd.CommandText=sSQL

        objCmd.parameters.append objCmd.CreateParameter("@kundenummer", adVarChar,     adParamInput, 150, Session("kundenummer"))
        objCmd.parameters.append objCmd.CreateParameter("@rkibrugernummer", adVarChar,     adParamInput, 150, Session("rkibrugernummer"))
        For populating recordset do the following:
        Set recordsetobject = .Execute
            Set Rec = objCmd.Execute()
       While NOT Rec.EOF
            Rec.MoveNext
        Wend
        Set objCmd = Nothing

         End If
```

Its gives me an Oracle Error "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle error '80040e14'  ORA-00936: missing expression.On line no 49. (set Rec=objCmd.Execute) may be something wrong with the sql statement...tHIS Was basically done to prevent sql injection

Comment: Well, then print out the value of sSQL, and run it in a sql client to see the complete, constructed SQL statement.

Comment: If your debugs are showing `aktfilid` values, perhaps `Session("kundenummer")` gets null? But yes, printing/logging the actual command being executed will reveal what is wrong pretty quickly. What parameters are you setting,  since you don't seem to have any bind variables? And how are you preventing injection here, since you're building the command up form user input?